# My expandableListview is not expanding

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am unable to understand why my `ExpandableListView` is not expanding. I've checked my code several times but unable to find anythink. I have compared my code with other tutorials but can not find the solution. Anybody help me thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
public class All_Offers extends Fragment {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
private ProgressDialog sweetProgressDialog;
public static final String URL = "https://some link";
ArrayList<Offer_Model> Offers;
ArrayList<Offer_Model> Name;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    sweetProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext(), R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    sweetProgressDialog.setMessage(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.loading)));
    sweetProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_all__offers, container, false);
    Offers = new ArrayList<>();
    Name = new ArrayList<>();
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {

            Log.d("onGroupClick:", "worked");
            parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {


        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            // child click
            return false;
        }
    });
    show_Offers();


    return v;
}

private void show_Offers() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());


    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (response.isEmpty() || response == null || response.equals("0")) {
                sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Loading Restaurants, check your connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            try {
                //sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("tag", "response " + response);
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)

                {
                    JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                    Offers.add(new Offer_Model(jObj.getString("percentOff"), jObj.getString("details"), jObj.getString("restaurantID"), jObj.getString("restaurantName")));
                    Log.e("jObj", String.valueOf(jObj));
                    Name.add(new Offer_Model(jObj.getString("name")));
                    Log.e("Offers value", String.valueOf(Offers));
                    Log.e("Name value", String.valueOf(Name));
                }

                listAdapter = new Offer_adaptor(getActivity(), Name,Offers);
                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.i("myTag", e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("myTag", error.toString());
                    if (sweetProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        sweetProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {


    myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));
    myReq.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(myReq);
    sweetProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    sweetProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Offers...");
    sweetProgressDialog.show();
}
}
```

this is my `Adapter` class, i am setting group and child data and several other functions

```
public class Offer_adaptor extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
// header titles
private ArrayList<Offer_Model> _listDataHeader;
// child data in format of header title, child title
private ArrayList _listDataChild;

public Offer_adaptor(Context context, ArrayList<Offer_Model> listDataHeader, ArrayList<Offer_Model> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return (int) this._listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.size());


}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Offer_Model childText = (Offer_Model) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_child_list_item, null);
    }


    TextView percentOff = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.percentOff_et);
    percentOff.setText(childText.getDetails());
    TextView details = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.details_et);
    details.setText(childText.getPercentOff());
    TextView restaurantID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantID_et);
    restaurantID.setText(childText.getRestaurantID());
    TextView restaurantName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName_et);
    restaurantName.setText(childText.getRestaurantName());


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return (int) this._listDataChild.get(_listDataChild.size());

}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return _listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Offer_Model headerTitle = (Offer_Model) getGroup(groupPosition);
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_cardview, null);
    }

    ImageView Tic_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tic_img);
    ImageView Share_img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.share_img);
    ImageView lblListHeader = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_switcher);

    TextView Offer_Detail_Tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_detail_tv);
    Offer_Detail_Tv.setText(headerTitle.getName());




    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: it is not expanding probably because your `getChildrenCount` returns 0 always

Comment: in my getChildrenCount i have return a arraylist which have values

Comment: return (int) this._listDataChild.get(_listDataChild.size());

Comment: check in debug mode what does it return. I think it returns 0

Comment: i have check it in debug mode it has value

Comment: 0 is value too. Is the value larger than 0?

Comment: list size is 1 and its greater than 0

Comment: not the size, what does `this._listDataChild.get(_listDataChild.size())` return?

Comment: "percentOff":"SUPER25","details":"25","restaurantID":"25% off only on shopping worth more than 599\/- INR","restaurantName":"4"

Comment: and you are trying to cast it to int?

Comment: no i am trying to cast it to string

Comment: `return (int) this._listDataChild.get(_listDataChild.size());` no, you are casting it to int

Comment: ok when i remove the int it is giving me this error Invalid index 1, size is 1

Comment: can you give your skype id so i can share my code for better understanding

Comment: that's because list count in Java starts from 0, and you are trying to get the list item with index of this list's size, so if the list size is 1, then it has onthe the 0th item, and you are trying to ge the 1st

Comment: then what should i do

Comment: that depends on what you want. I am not sure what you should do because your code is not clear, and it is not clear what it should do. Just a wild guess: make your `getChildrenCount` return `this._listDataChild.get(groupPosition);`

Comment: it now expand thanks man